# Scrape specific text from table

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'book'
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.sg/s?k=Measuring+Tools+%26+Scales&i=home&crid=1011S67HHJSEW&sprefix=measuring+tools+%26+scales%2Chome%2C408&ref=nb_sb_noss']

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//h2/a/@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        rows = response.xpath('//table[@id="productDetails_techSpec_section_1"]//tr')
        table={}
        for row in rows:
            brand = row.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'Brand')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get()
            asin = row.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'ASIN')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get().replace('\u200e',"")
            table.update({'Brand':brand,'Asin':asin})
        yield table
```

I want to scrape only `brand` and `ASIN` from the table  I scape the text from the `product information` these is the link https://www.amazon.sg/Etekcity-Accurate-Measuring-Packages-Stainless/dp/B08BPB9T1N/ref=sr_1_1?crid=1011S67HHJSEW&keywords=Measuring%2BTools%2B%26%2BScales&qid=1643125635&s=home&sprefix=measuring%2Btools%2B%26%2Bscales%2Chome%2C408&sr=1-1&th=1
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need brand and ASIN you don't need to iterate through the whole table. You can use xpath to directly select those attributes. One way to do it is using *following*.

```
brand = response.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'Brand')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get()

asin = response.xpath("//th[@class='a-color-secondary a-size-base prodDetSectionEntry' and contains(text(), 'ASIN')]/following-sibling::td/text()").get()
```

You might need to clean up the resulting text a bit using str().strip(). All this xpath is saying is "find the th tag with the right class and with a text of 'Brand' or 'ASIN' then look ahead to the next TD tag and grab that text."

Comment: the code is working good but they will provide me `empty csv` is there any solution ?

Comment: csv? are you trying to load the data into a csv file? That's not a part of your original code.

Comment: I have edit the code can you help me know check the code why they give me empty csv file

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see any code that involves outputting into a CSV. I do know that Amazon detects and blocks scraping so I would check for that. Otherwise, if you are getting an empty CSV I would set a breakpoint on the xpath line to make sure you are fetching the data correctly.